# Create Vector from Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let us assume that there is a value, for example 12,  in every cell from A1 to A10. Using A1:A10 I can then access the ten values of 12. Is there an elegant way using Excel formulas to get the object consisting of ten 12's created by A1:A10 with having only one single 12 in A1, that is without the remaining values from A2 to A10?

Something like REPEATVALUE(12, 10)?

Comment: A1:A10 filled with 12's represents an *array* of 12's. You can use a constant array like `{12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12}` to represent the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You nearly had it!

=REPT(A1,10)

Regards

Comment: Sorry for my premature enthusiasm, but the string is not what I am looking for. I am rather looking for the object that would be created by A1:A10.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'object'. You mean the entries in A1:A10 are not identical? And that you wish to obtain a string concatenation of all ten?

Comment: I have already discussed it with my collague as well, the problem is also that I have difficulties getting across what I am actually looking for. I am also starting to think that there is no way around using VBA, where it is trivial.

With REPEATVALUE(12,10) I want to get the same output back, as if I had entered for example A1:A10 with ten 12s in A1:A10. However, I do not want to actually use the fields at all.

Comment: Sorry - I have no idea what you mean. Which "fields" do you not wish to use? And can you confirm what you meant in your last comment re "the object that would be created by A1:A10"?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how the question can be misinterpreted.
The asker (and me too) wants a vector of ten cells being created, containing a certain value, without having to put the value in ten cells.
In my case I want to do a linear regression where all x values have the value 1, without actually having to fill a column with only ones. I know the obtained slope will be the same as the mean value, but I'm not sure about the R^2 value, which is why I use the additional statistics. As for now I put a hidden column with the value 1, but obviously this is a bad idea if rows are going to be inserted without the hidden cells being refilled with the value 1.

Comment: I don't know the original asker's application, but in my case I could divide a column by itself to obtain a column of ones: =INDEX(LINEST($E18:$E31/F18:F31;$E18:$E31/$E18:$E31;FALSE;TRUE);3;1)

Answer (score -2):

1. Select the cells A1:A10
2. click in cell A1
3. type the value you wish repeated, in this case: 12
4. hold the "control" AND "shift" buttons while pressing "ENTER"
5. the value "12" should now be repeated in all cells A1:A10